# add event dynamically and enable event only when need in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to add event dynamically in tag.
I want to enable onblur event only when my conditon is true.

for example,

```
<input *ngIf='expression?(blur)=callFun():nothing'>
```

Any way to do this kind of thing in angular2.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tried it myself but you can do like this:

```
<input (blur)="expression ? callFun() : null">
```